# How to increase memory on the FPGA board?

Tags: fpga, memory, xilinx, zynq, artix-series-fpga

**Situation**

I'm running a driver code `driver.cc` on the FPGA board ([PYNQ-Z1](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/pynq-z1/reference-manual)) but it gives an error in the middle of the code where the code calls to `cma_alloc(size, cached)` function, which returns a `NULL` pointer after a few runs. I believe this is because the board doesn't have enough memory because the board has only 512 MB of DDR3.

To be more specific about the environment:

- The `driver.cc` is running on the processing system (PS) of the board, which is an ARM Cortex-A9 processor.
- The OS Linux is booted from a microSD card (8 GB) loaded with image from this GitHub [repository](https://github.com/Xilinx/PYNQ).

**Question**

What are some possible ways to solve this problem, or to increase the memory?

---

<sub>Note: I have read a similar [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323186/increase-the-memory-on-the-fpga) before but the answers weren't quite clear to me. Also, to be more specific and to answer duskwuff's comment in the previous question, I have includeed information about the PS/PL and the OS setup environment.</sub>

Comment: Could you use the RAM more efficiently? For example, the program might be using 4 bytes for some value where 1 byte would be enough. Or perhaps there are some memory deallocations missing.

Comment: How much memory are you trying to allocate?

Comment: Back in the olden days, you could sometimes see something like [this](http://quinndunki.com/blondihacks/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/IMG_2130-600x800.jpg). I suppose doing that with the kind of packages used now is a little impractical, though.

Comment: How much memory are you trying to allocate, in total (Not just this call)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I do not have much knowledge about managing the behavior of memory allocation. The code in my driver calls to `cma_alloc` which seems to be declared/implemented/linked (not sure) in this Xilinx github [repository](https://github.com/Xilinx/PYNQ/search?q=cma_alloc&unscoped_q=cma_alloc)

Comment: 512MB with embedded Linux is pretty good, really. I would recommend you first look for memory leaks, but your main problem is you are trying to get cma memory repeatedly - hard to do over time. I recommend if you really want to use CMA, do it once and reuse, or use the device tree to reserve a block of memory out of the kernel - a so-called memory hole. especially if you HAVE to try and get coherent memory  more than once.  If you really want cma, do it once as soon as possible.  But safest is memory hole, in my opinion.  wrote a dma driver yesterday using this method

Comment: The memory allocation size & pattern varies depending on the upper application running. But from what I tried to debug, it calls `cma_alloc` with `size=4194304` 5-6 times and `size=11075584` 2-3 times, before it stops.

Comment: or, as I assume you are doing DMA, use scatter-gather on user pages

Comment: I would still recommend that if you want to use the continous allocator, reserve a chuck at probe time and keep it.  I think you'll find that other drivers will do this often as well

Comment: Thanks for all comments. It seems to be beyond my knowledge; I think I need some time to look into all your suggestions before coming back.

Answer (score 1):

The ram on the PYNQ-Z1 is a 256x16 module DDR3. They do make a [512x16 module](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=IS43TR16512AL-125KBL) in the same package. I haven't torn through the datasheet to see if they are directly compatible, but it looks close at first glance. If the chips are indeed compatible, you would need to find a BGA rework place to do the work of replacement.

[image]

PYNQ-Z1 DDR3 Schematic 
[image]

It would be much easier to adjust your algorithm to use less memory, if you can store data (with slower access times) then store it on the SD card.

Another avenue would be to use a slower serial RAM with the GPIO pins. But also not recommended, as you would have to find a compatible RAM (Arduino shields may be compatible with the PYNQ just by glancing at it and they do have serial RAM shields) You would have to install the shield and write a hardware driver for it, then map it into your program memory.